# Is there a way to see the remaining battery life of your keyboard/mouse on Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kde, plasma

I am just wondering. KDE sends me a notification if there is 10% battery life left on my keyboard, which is wireless. But is there a way to get the whole battery status data?

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) first and then learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Which kind of wireless battery is it? Bluetooth? Does it use some proprietary dongle?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Battery information is provided to desktop environments by [UPower](https://upower.freedesktop.org/); this includes the battery information for some keyboards and mice. You can see what your computer knows about its batteries by running

```
upower --dump
```

For example, on my desktop with a wireless Logitech mouse, it shows (among other things)

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/mouse_0003o046Do101Bx0006
  native-path:          /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:101B.0006
  vendor:               Logitech, Inc.
  model:                M705
  serial:               XXXXXXXX
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Mon 27 Aug 2018 15:41:36 CEST (106 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       no
  mouse
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    percentage:          25%
    icon-name:          'battery-low-symbolic'
```

On my laptop, it shows the laptop batteries, and the battery status of connected battery-powered devices.

Answer (score 2):

On KDE5 the "Battery and Brightness" systray widget also reports the battery level of connected devices (when it can):

[image]

(The M705 is my wireless mouse)

Comment: It’s weird that your M705 is reported twice ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt `lsusb` seems to report two interfaces for that mouse.

Comment: @xenod even stranger! There should only be one “Unifying Receiver” in the `lsusb` output (unless you have several obviously), and no M705 device shown there.